# Prevent propagation using USB devices

Tags: usb, content-filtering

I am thinking about a software capable to filter out the access to USB devices. As an example, only the process iexplorer.exe is allowed to copy files to the USB device.

The use case that I try to cover could be an infected computer where a malware running in memory tries to infect all USB devices connected to the system.

This software should prevent that to happen.

I checked McAfee DLP solution but it does not seem to cover this use case.